# Retorno do conteúdo por cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou desenvolvendo um gerador de boletos automático, utilizando uma ferramenta disponibilizada pelo banco Banrisul.
Para gerar esse boleto automático preciso enviar uma requisição através da seguinte URL:
    https://ww8.banrisul.com.br/brb/link/Brbw2Lhw_Bloqueto_Titulos_Internet.aspx

Os dados que informei nesse link são fictícios, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de obter o retorno desse boleto gerado automaticamente por cURL? Como posso fazer para que o boleto seja aberto de forma que facilite a impressão?

Obrigado.

Comment: Bom, você vai ter um pequeno complicador neste caso, pois o conteúdo do boleto em si é gerado num frame e chamado por JS. Se você simplesmente pegar o resultado do cURL, não vai ter o boleto.

Comment: @Bacco o certo seria criar uma pop-up então?

Comment: Dificil dizer o que é melhor neste caso, depende da aplicação. Na dúvida, só disponibilize um link/botão e ponha um aviso embaixo dizendo que o usuário será direcionado ao sistema do banco. Tem coisa que não compensa complicar.

Comment: @Bacco Entendo, tentei de várias formas obter uma resposta para esse problema, pois o Gerente solicitou algo diferente do que terá que ser feito. Por isso a minha pergunta aqui no StackOverflow.

Comment: Explique pra ele que o site usa um frame gerado por javascript, etc... (quem sabe ele não entenda e desista de complicar :) )

Comment: @Bacco vai ter que ser assim mesmo. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Para ler a página que roda JavaScript para ser gerada eu usei uma vez essa lib https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Por que é muito ampla a minha pergunta?

Comment: Pegue o action do form, e os campos que o form possui. Monte um CURL com o conteúdo exatamente igual. Inspecionar o elemento e verificar a aba network pode ajudar a ver o que o form atual envia e para onde envia

Após montar um CURL que simule exatamente o form, voce terá o resultado direto, onde poderá recuperar a URL que o banco disponibiliza para o boleto

Tente usar a aba network do navegador, e veja todas as ações que a pagina faz, e vá fazendo exatamente igual com CURL

Answer (score 2):

Tome cuidado com o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` ele de ser setado para true para verificar a conexão segura (já sofri muito com isso).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

Segundo, para exibir isso ai com o cURL basta recuperar a resposta do **curl_exec** e imprimir ela para seus usuários. Acho que não deveria alterar a opção de imprimir que o banco já disponibiliza, ele é boa e funciona bem em qualquer navegador.

Comment: A minha resposta está vindo vazia, o que poderia causar isso?

Teria algum exemplo para me dar que eu consiga imprimir na tela em uma modal?

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi corretamente você está perguntando como faz para pegar o retorno do cURL.
Neste caso lhe recomendo utilizar a função [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), passando por parametro:

- A conexão cURL
- A opção CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
- 1 ou true

Passando estas opções você informa ao cURL que o retorno da url deverá voltar para você quando invocar a função [curl_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) ao invés de ser exibido diretamente no browser.

Comment: Está me retornando um array vazio, o que pode ser?

Comment: Provavelmente está ocorrendo algum erro.
Para testar por erros tente o seguinte:
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, ...OPCOES QUE EU QUERO CONFIGURAR....);
    $retorno = curl_exec($ch);
    $erro = curl_errno($ch);
    $erroMsg = curl_error($ch);

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a impressão, o Banrisul já disponibiliza um link na página gerada com essa funcionalidade.

No seu caso, eu abriria o link num pop-up e deixaria a pessoa clicar no imprimir.

Comment: A ideia é ter uma opção de confirmar inscrição e imprimir/enviar por e-mail o boleto, por isso comentei sobre pegar somente o boleto.